# How to make code repeat itself every second (Trading Toolbox)

Tags: matlab

I recently came across the Trading Toolbox in matlab and I was very excited to find out you can do automated trading with it. I read the documentation, which was pretty clear, a couple of functions to connect to a certain broker, some order functions and a disconnect function. What I couldn't find out though is how you can make sure that your code is run constantly, otherwise automated trading isn't possible since trades can only be made or closed once every time you run your code. That shouldn't be the case, the code should be repeated every second or minute for that matter. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: You can use a [`timer`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html) object to run a script or function periodically

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for! It was little difficult for me to find because I have no experience with matlab. One more question though, isn't there anything special built-in the Trading Toolbox for this purpose?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used that toolbox